# Find out if a resque job is still running and kill it if it's stuck

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, redis, resque

I have an application that uses resque to run some long-running jobs. Sometimes the take 8 hours or more to complete.

In situations where the job fails, is there a way to monitor resque itself to see if the job is running? I know I can update the job's status in a database table (or in redis itself), but I want to know if the job is still running so I can kill it if necessary.

The specific things I need to do are:

- Determine if the job is still running
- Determine if the job has stopped
- Kill jobs that are stuck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resque [github repository](https://github.com/resque/resque) has this secret gem, a [god](http://godrb.com/) task that will do exactly this: watch your tasks and kill stale ones.

https://github.com/resque/resque/blob/master/examples/god/stale.god

```
# This will ride alongside god and kill any rogue stale worker
# processes. Their sacrifice is for the greater good.

WORKER_TIMEOUT = 60 * 10 # 10 minutes

Thread.new do
  loop do
    begin
      `ps -e -o pid,command | grep [r]esque`.split("\n").each do |line|
        parts   = line.split(' ')
        next if parts[-2] != "at"
        started = parts[-1].to_i
        elapsed = Time.now - Time.at(started)

        if elapsed >= WORKER_TIMEOUT
          ::Process.kill('USR1', parts[0].to_i)
        end
      end
    rescue
      # don't die because of stupid exceptions
      nil
    end

    sleep 30
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It seems clear that this will kill jobs that have run past a particular period of time (though without determining whether the job is stuck or just still processing). The jobs I'm running can take a few minutes to 24 or more hours depending on the underlying data.

Comment: @KevinBedell: you can set timeout to 36-48 hours then :)

Comment: Yeah - that's true. I think I need to combine this with a way to monitor progress of the job directly so I can see if it's still working.

Comment: @KevinBedell: yes, it shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: naive question here: what to do with this script? can i load it up along with my god config? or start another watch on this?

Comment: Just require it in god config.

Comment: Just gonna throw this in here.  I think Bee has an excellent question and I think this question is relevant in many, many cases.  When sharing code with one another we should share context for *where* the code should be included into our projects.

Answer (score 1):

The god solution ends up killing off workers that possibly aren't stuck or bad at all. I started working on addressing this issue as well via a different approach. You do whatever you want - register a handler (can kill, email, send a pager alert, etc) when any resque problems come up.

If a job doesn't get processed during a certain timeframe (either because resque is stuck, the queue has an insane backlog, or resque just isn't running at all), the handler will get invoked. Feel free to poke at the README for more details.

https://github.com/shaiguitar/resque_stuck_queue#readme